# Code builds fine in VS (2017) but not msbuild or TFS "assemblies manifest does not match the assembly reference

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget, tfsbuild

OK - here we go again. I posted an almost identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456605/why-does-msbuild-fail-while-building-within-vs-builds-fine?noredirect=1#comment85919126_49456605), but this one is a little different. I just generated a new version of a NuGet package and updated all of our csproj and config files to point to it and it builds locally fine, but when I kick off a TFS build it fails with the message:

> ##[error]ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'PacsgearLib, Version=2.5.4.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=05b30ac9ab9dbb8e' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Pacsgearlib 2.5.4 is the NuGet package I just generated, but all of our other projects build fine (and they share a lot of the same code). The main difference is that this project has a website in it. MSBuild is version 15.5.180.51428.

Here's a picture of the actual error:

[image]

Any ideas here? I've tried NuGet package manager to uninstall the package and reinstall it for the website and that hasn't helped.

I've been at this for a few hours so I thought maybe someone else (or a second set of eyes) might help.

I also just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134304/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-referenc) and will check it out first thing Monday morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work by taking out the assemblybinding section of the web.config (someone else suggested that in another related post) and I also found a few .csproj files that had not been properly updated and were still pointing at 2.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

If the local builds fine, and the error exist with TFS build.  Besides, all of our other projects build fine (and they share a lot of the same code).

Combine with both, the issue may related to the specific package `PacsgearLib, Version=2.5.4.0` on build agent.  You could try to delete the packages and clean build agent, then try again.

Another way is update your package version number(do not update the package content), use TFS trigger the build again. Check if TFS build server will pick up the latest version of package.

Also set `system.debug=true` to [Enable Verbose Debug Mode](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/) with more detail log info for troubleshooting

Comment: I tried deleting the package and re-kicking off a build and it didn't help. I also turned on verbose debugging and that doesn't help either.  (The log around the error is identical).

Comment: BTW, when I generate a new NuGet package and kick off a TFS build it always fails to get the new package to the build server. I have to open the solution on the build server and restore packages manually and then the build goes through. Any idea why this would happen? I tried adding a NuGet step to the build but that doesn't seem to work. And generating a new NuGet package is a major pain that requires me to change all ~130 or so .csproj and .config files that reference it. Maybe I'll try that if nothing else works.